# run jupyter notebook using a dynamic name/string from another notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

One can run a Jupyter notebook from another notebook using the `%run` magic:

```
%run my_notebook.ipynb
```

However, I have the path and name of the notebook I wish to run in a python variable, `notebook_name`.

Is it possible to run this notebook using the `%run` magic? If not, how else might I run the notebook using its name contained in a `str` variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$` to evaluate Python variables for Jupyter magic functions in general, much like in a shell:

```
%run $notebook_name
```

Comment: are these local variables, or environment variables, or both?

Comment: @RickTeachey Python variables, either local or global.